# ie8 Member not found when setting style

Tags: javascript, css, dhtml

This code works fine in firefox, when Search button clicked, an image pops inside the myText box, right aligned:

```
function showImg(){
   var setStyle = document.getElementById('myText').style == 
     "background-color:white" ? 
     document.getElementById('myText').style = 
     "background: url(/somePath/someImg.gif) no-repeat; background-position:right; background-color:white" : 
     document.getElementById('myText').style == "background-color:white";}

 <input type="text" id="myText">

 <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="showImg()">
```

but in IE8 throws "Member not found". it's definitely related to setting the style, but i can't figure how to get around it

thanks for any help

#

thanks everybody for answering. cssText works when trying to detect an existing style string, but not when trying to set it (won't throw an error, but no image either). If i try to use style= to set it, i get the Member not found error. That makes me think that trying to preload the image with visibility:hidden woudn't work either

```
 function showImg(){
 if (document.getElementById('myText').cssText = "background-color:white"){ 
alert("style detected"); // this works
document.getElementById('myText').cssText="background: url(/somePath/someImg.gif) no-repeat; background-position:right; background-color:white";  // this doesn't
} else { alert("style not detected"); }}

 <input type="text" id="myText" style="background-color:white">
 <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="showImg()">
```

#### #

i found kind of a solution, works as a toggle in IE8 (img appears/disappears onClick inside text box). However, in firefox, it appears/disappears only once (!) then does nothing. Would somebody know how to fix that?

i've created a second, invisible image (one pixel, transparent), and i'm switching them

```
 picShow=new Image(); 
 picShow.src="/somePath/realImage.gif"; 
 picHide=new Image(); 
 picHide.src="/somePath/invisibleImage.gif"; 

 function showImg() {
var imgPath = new String();
imgPath = document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundImage;

if (imgPath == "url(/somePath/invisibleImage.gif)" || imgPath == "") {
    document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundImage = "url(/somePath/realImage.gif)";
    document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundRepeat="no-repeat";
    document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundPosition="right";
} else {
    document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundImage = "url(/somePath/invisibleImage.gif)";
}
```

}

#### #

ahhh, firefox creates the backgroundImage putting the url within double quotes, like url("/somePath/invisibleImage.gif"), but IE doesn't. just have to escape them for firefox. this is the working code, just in case someone else needs it. Thanks again everybody!

```
 picShow=new Image(); 
 picShow.src="/somePath/realImage.gif"; 
 picHide=new Image(); 
 picHide.src="/somePath/invisibleImage.gif"; 

 function showImg() {
var imgPath = new String();
imgPath = document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundImage;

if (imgPath == "url(/somePath/invisibleImage.gif)" || imgPath == "url(\"/somePath/invisibleImage.gif\")" || imgPath == "") {
    document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundImage = "url(/somePath/realImage.gif)";
    document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundRepeat="no-repeat";
    document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundPosition="right";
} else {
    document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundImage = "url(/somePath/invisibleImage.gif)";
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Where you have used `.style` use `.cssText` instead.

Example:

```
 document.getElementById('myText').cssText == "background-color:white";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you can not set the style like that and using a ternary operator like that is a bad idea.  You would need to use `cssText`.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myText');
var style = (elem.cssText == "background-color:white" ? "background: url(/somePath/someImg.gif) no-repeat; background-position:right; background-color:white" : 
     "background-color:white";
elem.cssText = style;
```

A better solution is just setting a CSS class and have a rule in your stylesheet that corresponds.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myText');
var className = (elem.className=="active") ? "" : "active";
elem.className = className;
```

and the CSS

```
#myText{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#myText.active {
    background: url(/somePath/someImg.gif) no-repeat; 
    background-position:right;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

firefox creates the backgroundImage putting the url within double quotes, like 
url("/somePath/invisibleImage.gif"), but IE8 doesn't. just have to escape them for firefox. this is the working code, just in case someone else needs it.

```
 picShow=new Image(); 
 picShow.src="/somePath/realImage.gif"; 
 picHide=new Image(); 
 picHide.src="/somePath/invisibleImage.gif"; 

 function showImg() {
 var imgPath = new String();
 imgPath = document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundImage;

 if (imgPath == "url(/somePath/invisibleImage.gif)" || imgPath == "url(\"/somePath/invisibleImage.gif\")" || imgPath == "") {
document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundImage = "url(/somePath/realImage.gif)";
document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundRepeat="no-repeat";
document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundPosition="right";
} else {
document.getElementById('myText').style.backgroundImage = "url(/somePath/invisibleImage.gif)";
}

<input type="text" id="myText">

<input type="button" value="Search" onClick="showImg()">
```